# guardar el campo password encriptado en hash - php

Tags: php

Al guardar en mi metodo put requiero que la variable "password" me guarde encriptado en hash y al cargar en mi metodo get que me cargue la contraseña pero en el valor real y no encriptado para poder visualizar posteriormente el password en php.

```html
<?php

include '../bd/global.php';

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $query="select * from users where id=".$_GET['id'];
        $resultado=metodoGet($query);
        echo json_encode($resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    }else{
        $query="select * from users where rol ='usuario'";
        $resultado=metodoGet($query);
        echo json_encode($resultado->fetchAll()); 
    }
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    exit();
}

if($_POST['METHOD']=='PUT_administrador'){
    unset($_POST['METHOD']);
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $query="UPDATE users SET name='$name', password='$password' WHERE id='$id'";
    $resultado=metodoPut($query);
    echo json_encode($resultado);
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    exit();
}


header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");


?>
```

Comment: Hola. Es muy simple: al momento del INSERT o del UPDATE tendrías que usar **[`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php)** para guadar la clave encriptada y para verificarla tendrías que usar **[`password_verify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php)**, es decir al momento del `SELECT`. ¿Revisaste la documentación y los ejemplos de ambas funciones en el Manual de PHP? ¿Cuál es tu problema concreto?

Comment: hola, necesito implementar lo que mencionas pero en mi algoritmo php, como quedaria?, necesito que mi metodo "PUT" la variable password guarde en password_hash y mi metodo "GET" cuando cargue que el campo password cargue el password pero que no aparezca encriptado si no el valor real de la calve para poder visualizarlo posteriormente.

Comment: Te puse los enlaces a la documentación. ¿La leíste? ¿Viste los ejemplos? ¿Qué estás intentando una vez leída la documentación? A partir de ese punto podremos ayudarte. El problema es que ahora mismo no muestras ningún esfuerzo por al menos entender cómo funciona y ensayar un código. Es importante que leas la doc, hay cosas importantes allí que conviene que sepas o podrías errar gravemente con tus contraseñas.

Comment: @Giovanny Para hacer una aclaración... Por seguridad, el password no se guarda encriptado, se almacena es un hash del password (cosa que es completamente distinta). No existe un método para convertir un hash en el password original. Si realmente tu requisito es mostrar el password original, no puedes almacenarlo como un hash (cosa que no recomiendo).

Comment: Esto se hace justamente así, para que si alguien logra tener acceso a la base de datos, y leer los datos de la tabla de usuarios, solo vea los hash de los passwords y no las contraseñas directamente.

Comment: listo, pero en el caso de mi metodo "GET" como hago para poder visualizar las contraseñas  ya que si cargo asi el campo password me va es a mostrar el codigo hash de mi contraseña y no la contraseña como tal.

Comment: Por eso digo... si está almacenado el hash, no hay forma de mostrar la contraseña original

Comment: No manipules la contraseña en texto plano. Si tienes esa duda, la pregunta siempre será ¿realmente necesitas hacerlo?

Comment: Si **realmente** necesitaras hacer algo así, la única solución viable que veo es que guardes la contraseña original en una tabla a la que nadie tenga acceso, solamente tú como Super Administrador. Aún así, hay un margen de riesgo, si alguien explota tu contraseña de Super Administrador accederá a las contraseñas tal cual. Como comenta @Alfabravo, hay que preguntarse por qué querrías asumir ese riesgo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que usar la funcion pasword_hash() de la siguiente manera, ten en cuenta que el campo donde vallas a guardar el hash de la contraseña, debe permitir minimo 60 caracteres:

Documentacion de PHP - Password Hash: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php

Documentacion de PHP - Password Verify: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php

EDIT: Para verificar la contraseña usas la funcion password_verify() de la siguente manera password_verify($ContraseñaQueIngresaElUsuario, $HashEnLaBaseDeDatos)

```
<?php

include '../bd/global.php';

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $query="select * from users where id=".$_GET['id'];
        $resultado=metodoGet($query);
        echo json_encode($resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    }else{
        $query="select * from users where rol ='usuario'";
        $resultado=metodoGet($query);
        echo json_encode($resultado->fetchAll()); 
    }
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    exit();
}

if($_POST['METHOD']=='PUT_administrador'){
    unset($_POST['METHOD']);
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    //Pasar a la variable $password por el metodo password_hash()
    $passCrypt = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
    //Aqui remplaze $password por $passCrypt
    $query="UPDATE users SET name='$name', password='$passCrypt' WHERE id='$id'";
    $resultado=metodoPut($query);
    echo json_encode($resultado);
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    exit();
}


header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");


?>
```

Comment: Lo que el pregunta es como obtener el password original y enviarlo en la respuesta